# How to get the onclick event params with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of radio buttons which have unique name and id but the value for each radio is same and onclick event, what I want to get is the parameters that are inside the click event of checked radio button on document ready.

```
<input id="lvCP_CP1_0_rbC_0" type="radio" name="lv$ctrl0$UC1$CP" value="rbC" checked="checked" onclick="SetCPPrice('lvCP_CP1_0_rbCPSelected_0','Total:5','CPID:wrAtPJQGUiuKfptENuMumY/M7utu6gZ3VMRy3KI1P9rNCokUUO','CPPriceUS:75.9878666666667','CPriceEU:107.53');">
```

Comment: Copy-paste your code of the function SetCPPrice first...

Comment: you can not have same name for ID , use a class Instead

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya _"which have unique name and id"_

Comment: Ai125 says ->I have a set of radio buttons which have unique name and id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var onClickAttribute = $('#lvCP_CP1_0_rbC_0').attr('onclick');
```

I have no idea why do you need it, but that's the way you can do it.

---

If you want to split the string to parameters:

```
var str = $('#lvCP_CP1_0_rbC_0').attr('onclick');   
var params = str.split("SetCPPrice(")[1].split(',');
params[params.length - 1] = params[params.length - 1].replace(');');
console.log(params);​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Er5ze/)

**Disclaimer**: you shouldn't really use this.

Comment: i have tried your solution but while debugging i get list of method. and not the params

Comment: is their another appropriate way to do it, what i want to do is get the this values and fill them to hiddenfields for the selected radio button

Comment: @AI25. You're asking for a good answer to a horrible demand. You shouldn't store data in the `onclick` attribute per se. You can store it in `data-*` attributes. :)

Comment: @gdoron 's comment about data-* should be edited into the formal answer.  It solved my similar problem without any code wrangling.

Comment: @Jigarb1992 replace `,` with something that shouldn't exist in the text, such as `~~~`. Good luck.

Comment: @gdoron I cant change it

Comment: @Jigarb1992, I suggest you open a new question.